# Unable to navigate to a new screen on marker click in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am using google maps in angularJS and I am new to AngularJS.
I am trying to navigate to a new screen on click of marker using $location but I am unable to do it.Getting path not defined error. Can some one help.

```
var myapp = angular.module("googleApp", ['ngRoute']);
```

myapp.controller("initMap",initMap('$location','$path'))

function initMap($location,$path){
    var loaction1 = {lat: 17.3850, lng:  78.4867};

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 5,
      center: loaction2
    });
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: loaction1,
      map: map
    });

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<p>Marker Location:' + marker1.getPosition() + '</p>'
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker1);
      });

     var selectedLocation = [{"lat":0,"long":0}];
      marker1.addListener('click', function() {
        map.setZoom(7);
        map.setCenter(marker1.getPosition());
        // console.log("Click registered" + marker1.getPosition());
        selectedLocation[0].lat = marker1.getPosition().lat();
        selectedLocation[0].long = marker1.getPosition().lng();

        console.log("Latitude is " + selectedLocation[0].lat +    "Longitude is " + selectedLocation[0].long);
        var check = false;



        $location.path("/valuePage.html");

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $location.path("\"); try this one 
$scope.showNextPage("file name");
If file is in same folder
Otherwise $scope.showNextPage("path");

Comment: Its saying "Cannot read property 'showNextPage' of undefined".